# Comparing 2 excel files using a primary key

Tags: python, compare

I have two excel files, small example is as shown below

Name    Item1   Item2   Item3
abc 123 abc 12AD
Efg 456 Tree    78YT

Name    Item2   Item1   Item3
abc 123 abc 12AD
Efg 456 Tree    78YT

The common key here is "Name". I need to compare the files using the unique id : Name and then match with the column names (item1..) and then compare the values

The results should be shown as below:
Name and the values which are not matching

Name  File1_Item 2  File2_Item2

abc    abc           123
Efg    Tree          456

Can you suggest how to handle this if there are 300 columns and 10000 records

I did write a code about comparing cell values...
Pls see the code below..Need help on changing it to match the above requirement:

```
# Libraries
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell


#Reading the files
    template = "File1"
    testSheet = "File2"

    rt,ct = template.shape
    rtest,ctest = testSheet.shape

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns['Cell_Location','Source_Value','Target_Value'])


    for rowNo in range(max(rt,rtest)):
        for colNo in range(max(ct,ctest)):
    # Fetching the template value at a cell
    #print (rowNo,colNo)
            try:
             template_val = template.iloc[rowNo,colNo]

            except:
             template_val = np.nan

    # Fetching the testsheet value at a cell
            try:
             testSheet_val = testSheet.iloc[rowNo,colNo]

            except:
            testSheet_val = np.nan

    # Comparing the values
            if (str(template_val)!=str(testSheet_val)):
             cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(rowNo, colNo)

                    dfTemp = pd.DataFrame([[cell,template_val,testSheet_val]],
              columns= ['Cell_Location','Source_Value','Target_Value'])
               df = df.append(dfTemp)`
     print df
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a join:

```
new_df = df1.set_index("Name").join(df2.set_index("Name"))
```

After that, you can do a selection with:

```
new_df.loc[new_df.df1_column1 != new_df.df2_column1]
```

If you want to select the row in which the above columns are different

Comment: Can we do that in a loop, if there is a mismatch then get the columns being compared and store it/publish it

Comment: after you do the join you can select with new_df.loc[new_df.df1_column1 != new_df.df2_column1]

Comment: you can do that in a loop of course, but that would be less efficient

Comment: This solution wouldn't work because the columns are not in the same order